# JavaScript - Input Submit Button (html) to activate JavaScript Function Not Working

Tags: javascript

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <script>
            function calculate(){
                var salary = document.forms["calculateForm"]["salary"].value;
                document.getElementById("werd").getInnerHTML = salary;
                return false;
            }
        </script>
        <title> Question </title>
    </head>
    <body onload = "calculate()">
        <form action = "" id = "calculateForm" onsubmit = "return calculate();">
            Salary: 
            <input type = "text" name = "salary" value = "95000" style="background-color:lightgray" required>
            <input type = "submit" value = "Submit">
        </form>
        <p id = "werd"> Text that should be replaced with the entered salary upon clicking Submit which runs a JavaScript function </p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Hello,

Upon entering a salary and pressing "Submit", the paragraph with id="werd" should be updated to the salary as a result of the calculate() function being invoked. Why is this not happening?

I spent 3-4 hours trying to fix this and looked up a lot of solutions on google. Any solutions (other than learning jQuery, etc.)?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Change it from `getInnerHTML` to `innerHTML` and it all works.

```js
function calculate() {
  var salary = document.forms["calculateForm"]["salary"].value;
  document.getElementById("werd").innerHTML = salary;
  return false;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title> Question </title>
</head>

<body onload="calculate()">
  <form action="" id="calculateForm" onsubmit="return calculate();">
    Salary:
    <input type="text" name="salary" value="95000" style="background-color:lightgray" required>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>
  <p id="werd"> Text that should be replaced with the entered salary upon clicking Submit which runs a JavaScript function </p>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById("werd").getInnerHTML = salary;
```

Change to

```
document.getElementById("werd").innerHTML = salary;
```